# TypeError: can't access property "error", data is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

got the title error and can't fix it :(. I'm triying to get the data from a signup page, here is my javascript code:

```
const SignupComponent = () => {
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    name: 'ryan',
    email: 'ryan@gmail.com',
    password: 'rrrrrr',
    error: '',
    loading: false,
    message: '',
    showForm: true
});

const { name, email, password, error, loading, message, showForm } = values;

const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.table({ name, email, password, error, loading, message, showForm });
    setValues({ ...values, loading: true, error: false });
    const user = { name, email, password };

    signup(user).then(data => {
        if(data.error) {
            setValues({ ...values, error: data.error, loading: false });
        } else {
            setValues ({ ...values, name: '', email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false, message: data.message, showForm: false});
        }
    });
};

const handleChange = name => e => {
    setValues({ ...values, error: false, [name]: e.target.value })
```

, so when i try to register in the page, its says TypeError: can't access property "error", data is undefined.

```
              signup(user).then(data => {
> 25 |             if(data.error) {
     |               ^
  26 |                 setValues({ ...values, error: data.error, loading: false });
  27 |             } else {
```

Signup Function

```
export const signup = (user) => { 
    return 
    fetch(${API}/signup, { method: 'POST', 
   headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 
   'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, 
    body: JSON.stringify(user) }) 
   .then(response => { return response.json(); }) 
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

i'm kinda nooby in programming but i already look in the internet for a solution, nothing works u.U

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where does the 'signup' function come from and what does it look like?

Comment: Thanks! it comes from my auth file, it looks like:

export const signup = (user) => {
    return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

Answer (score 0):

When you called `json()` method in fetch response a Promise is returned since reading a stream object will happen aysnchronously. So what you is to chain another then function to get that data like this.

```
export const signup = user => {
  return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { Accept: "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      return data;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

PS: neither you need to use `async`/ `await` since you are using Promises with `.then()`, nor there is any need for chaining with one more `.then()` inside `signup()` since you are already doing that in `handleSubmit()` where you've called `signup()`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Shubham Gupta I forget the handleSubmit() method part.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks you so much, i tried it but now i'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined, it seems like now it's getting data but think that now need to define error, how can i do that?

Comment: Hello may be you can trace it by logging first the data if it has the `error` property. 

`signup(user).then(data => console.log(data));

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not quite familiar with the concept of Asynchronous programming. Fetch is an `Async` function and if you want to wait for it's output you have to you use the `Await` keyword which also requires `signup` to be Async. So your code will look some what like this:

```js
export const signup = async (user) => { 
    
    let fetchResponse = fetch(${API}/signup, { method: 'POST', 
   headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 
   'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, 
    body: JSON.stringify(user) });

    return (await fetchResponse.json())
```

To Learn more about Asynchronous programming, I recommend reading this article https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

Try re-writing your `signup()` function as below. I guess you've missed back-ticks because I've implemented the SignUp in a similar way and it works for me. Let me know if it helps:

```
export const signup = (user) => { 
    return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json', 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }, 
     body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    }) 
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

PS: neither you need to use `async/await` since you are using Promises with `.then()`, nor there is any need for chaining with one more `.then()` inside `signup()` since you are already doing that in `handleSubmit()` where you've called `signup()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks you so much, i tried it but now i'm getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined, it seems like now it's getting data but think that now need to define error, how can i do that?

Comment: @MaykolSalgado Did you try logging `data`? If it's saying `Cannot read property 'error' of undefined`, then your `data` is still undefined. If that's the case, maybe you'll have to check once your `signup` route.